# Molecule cannot connect to docker

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-desktop, molecule

I cannot make molecule test. I got error as below:

```
fatal: [instance]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to create temporary directory. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1667246171.1306775-8118-8192388989455 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1667246171.1306775-8118-8192388989455=\"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1667246171.1306775-8118-8192388989455 `\" ), exited with result 1", "unreachable": true}
```

In `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` I added `remote_tmp = /tmp` and cleared `./cache` dir.
It didn't bring any update.

I'm running WSL2 and Docker Desktop (4.13), "Integration" is enabled for WSL in Docker Desktop settings.

Comment: you need to show your molecule config and let us know what molecule command you are running

Comment: Is your docker instance running after molecule has created it?

Comment: I have the same issue.

`molecule.yml` :

Comment: `
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: docker
platforms:
  - name: debian11
    image: debian:11-slim
    command: ""
    tmpfs:
      - /run
      - /tmp
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw
    pre_build_image: false
    dockerfile: ../../templates/Dockerfile.j2
    privileged: true
    cgroupns_mode: host
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  inventory:
    host_vars:
      debian11:
        ansible_user: user1
  config_options:
    defaults:
      remote_tmp: /tmp
  log: true
verifier:
  name: ansible
  `

Comment: `Dockerfile.j2`

FROM debian:11-slim


ENV ANSIBLE_USER=user1 DEPLOY_GROUP=deployer
ENV SUDO_GROUP='sudo'
ENV name USER

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install sudo

RUN set -xe \
  && groupadd -r ${ANSIBLE_USER} \
  && groupadd -r ${DEPLOY_GROUP} \
  && useradd -m -g ${ANSIBLE_USER} ${ANSIBLE_USER} \
  && usermod -aG ${SUDO_GROUP} ${ANSIBLE_USER} \
  && usermod -aG ${DEPLOY_GROUP} ${ANSIBLE_USER} \
  && sed -i "/^%${SUDO_GROUP}/s/ALL\$/NOPASSWD:ALL/g" /etc/sudoers

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/echo", "Welcome, $name"]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ubuntu 22.04.2 try this

1. Install [docker](https://%20https://github.com/docker/docker-install) on WSL
2. Pull the image you use on molecule (E.G. geerlingguy/docker-centos7-ansible)
3. use localhost as a hosts in converge file to use the wsl host.
4. Make  sure you use sudoer user with No password

Faced this today and fixed with these simple step, basically the culprit would be using `hosts: all`